# Is it possible to access and edit Google documents directly from Libreoffice?

Tags: sync, spreadsheet, documents, libreoffice, google-docs

I'd like to work with a Google spreadsheet directly inside Libreoffice, without having to export and import it, in order to automatically reflect the changes on the online file.
Basically, I'm looking for a way to use Libreoffice as a kind of interface to Google online documents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a Libreoffice extension named [OpenOffice.org2GoogleDocs](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/openoffice.org2googledocs-export-import-to-google-docs-zoho-webdav) that is aimed at this purpose.

It works by downloading the files from Google Drive to the computer hard disk in a user-chosen directory; it can download files from Google Drive and upload to that cloud service documents on the user's system. The whole process is made by downloading files, editing them, and then re-upload.

By selecting the autoupdate option (see image below) it automatically reflect the changes made on the offline file to its online counterpart (the filenames should be identical of course, make sure to remove the extension - `.odt`, `.ods` and so on - when choosing the filename from the sync dialog), effectively making libreoffice work like a frontend for Google Docs.

**NOTE:** this extension's last version is from June 2011, but it runs perfectly in Libreoffice 4. It requires Java to work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No longer works as of now :(
ubuntu version 14.04
libre office version 4.2

install error from libre office:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException